# How to set different colors for autotext and user-entered text

Tags: php, colors, command-line-interface, readline

I try to set a two different colors - blue color for "command>" and magenta for inputed text, but it not work, because readline_callback_handler_install() and readline() not allows a color codes.

[image]

For examples:

1. if you run

```php
<?php
readline("\033[35mcommand>");
```

using cli. you get result like this

[image]

2. if you try this example

```php
<?php
fputs(STDOUT, "\033[34mcommand>\033[35m");
readline(' ');
```

you get valid colors, but the 'command>' can be deleted.

[image]

I have a solution without readline_* functions, but it hasn't support of autocomplete.

current version of code is:

```php
class Dictionary
{
    const EXIT_COMMAND = 'exit';

    protected array $classesDictionary = [];

    protected array $methodsDictionary = [];

    private ?string $command = null;

    private ?bool $isRunned = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->isRunned = true;
        stream_set_blocking(STDIN, false);
        stream_set_blocking(STDOUT, false);
        $this->initCommandCompletionHandler();
        $this->showCmdString();
        while($this->isRunned) {
            $read = [STDIN];
            $write = null;
            $except = null;
            $streamCounts = stream_select($read, $write, $except, null);
            if ($streamCounts) {
                readline_callback_read_char();
            }
        }
    }

    public function showCmdString()
    {
        fputs(STDOUT, "\033[34mcommand> ");
        $command = fgets(STDIN);
      if (!empty(trim($command))) {
                fputs(STDOUT, "\033[31mHey! I don't know what are you talking about!");
                return false;
            $message = "You try to run command '{$command}'";
            if (!empty($param)) {
                $message .= " with param '{$param}'.";
            }
            fputs(STDOUT, $message . "\n");
        }
    }

    public function initCommandCompletionHandler()
    {
        $this->initClassesDictionary();
        fputs(STDOUT, "\033[34m");
        // Tab btn reaction
        readline_completion_function(
            function ($currWord, $stringPosition, $cursorInLine) {
                fputs(STDOUT, "\033[35m");
                $fullLine = readline_info()['line_buffer'];
                if (count( explode(' ', $fullLine) ) > 2 ) {
                    return $this->getArgumentsDescription($fullLine);
                }
                if (
                    (strrpos($fullLine, ' ') !== false &&
                    (
                        strrpos($fullLine, $currWord) ===  false ||
                        strrpos($fullLine, ' ') < strrpos($fullLine, $currWord))
                    )
                ) {
                    return $this->getMethodsList($fullLine);
                }
                return $this->classesDictionary;
            }
        );
        readline_callback_handler_install('>', function($str) {
            echo $str;
        });
    }

    private function getMethodsList(string $fullLine)
    {
        $arr = array_map(fn($item) => trim($item), explode(' ', $fullLine));
        return array_filter(
            array_map(
                fn($method) => "\033[32m".$method->getName()."\033[34m",
                (new \ReflectionClass('App\\Providers\\'.$arr[0].'\\Facade'))
                    ->getMethods(
                        \ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC |
                        \ReflectionMethod::IS_STATIC |
                        \ReflectionMethod::IS_FINAL)
            ),
            fn($methodName) => !in_array(
               strtolower($methodName),
                [
                    '__construct',
                    '__destruct',
                    '__sleep',
                    '__wakeup',
                    '__tostring'
                ]
            )
        );
    }

    private function getArgumentsDescription(string $fullLine)
    {
         $fullArr = explode(' ', trim($fullLine));
         $args = [];
         array_map(function($arg) use (&$args) {
             $type = ($arg->hasType()) ? $arg->getType()->getName() : 'mixed';
             $default = ($arg->isDefaultValueAvailable())
                 ? ($arg->getDefaultValue()) ? 'true' : 'false'
                 : "\033[31mnot have";
             $isNullable = ($arg->hasType())
                     ? ($arg->getType()->allowsNull()) ? 'true' : 'false'
                     : ' not typed';
             $isOptional = ($arg->isOptional()) ? 'true' : 'false';
             $isVariadic = ($arg->isVariadic()) ? 'true' : 'false';
             $args[$arg->getPosition()] =
                 "\033[32mposition: \033[33m{$arg->getPosition()}\033[32m;" .
                 "\033[32m name: \033[33m\${$arg->getName()}\033[32m; " .
                 "\033[32m type: \033[33m{$type}\033[32m; " .
                 "\033[32m default value: \033[33m{$default}\033[32m; " .
                 "\033[32m isNullable: \033[33m{$isNullable}\033[32m; " .
                 "\033[32m isOptional: \033[33m{$isOptional}\033[32m; " .
                 "\033[32m isVariadic: \033[33m{$isVariadic}\033[34m";
         },
         (new \ReflectionClass('App\\Providers\\'.$fullArr[0].'\\Facade'))
             ->getMethod(end($fullArr))
             ->getParameters());
         return $args;
    }

    public function readCommand($cmd)
    {
        if ($cmd === self::EXIT_COMMAND) {
            $this->isRunned = false;
            fputs(STDOUT, "\033[32m\n");
            readline_callback_handler_remove();
        }
    }

    private function initClassesDictionary()
    {
        $this->classesDictionary = array_filter(
            array_map(
                fn($dir) => basename($dir),
                glob('providers/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)
            ),
            fn($dir) => !in_array($dir, ['contracts'])
        );
        $this->classesDictionary[] = self::EXIT_COMMAND;
    }

    public function executeCommand($command)
    {
        $param = '';
        if (strpos($command, ' ') !== false) {
            list ($command, $param) = explode(' ', $command, 2);
        }

        if (!empty(trim($command))) {
            if (!$this->isCommandExists($command)) {
                fputs(STDOUT, "Hey! I don't know what are you talking about!\n");
                return false;
            }
            $message = "You try to run command '{$command}'";
            if (!empty($param)) {
                $message .= " and with param '{$param}'.";
            }
            fputs(STDOUT, $message . "\n");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should look for some libraries. You are assuming that terminal can show colours, and that such command for colours works on the terminal. On remote servers it is a huge assumption, and you make more difficult to have scriptable automatic answers. So: do not implement it yourself (but if you want to learn a lot about terminals (and remote terminals) and all complications. PS: I often use white terminals, so colours may sucks because bad programming practices).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't want to use monstrous huge libraries to solve such a simple task =)

Comment: It is not a simple task, really. The libraries are huge for a reason (if you are not reading `TERM` environment variable, and acting according [so with special code for different terminals], you are doing terminal handling wrong. If you want thing simple, keep it without colours and special commands. Else you are creating nightmares for some users.

Comment: I had a working version without colors, but with big datas it becomes unreadable. Using libraries from Symfony or similar will lead to too much code bloat. The task is to write a small script that will work on one single server and no more

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi can there be a way to intercept the processing of the Tab button? then I could quickly make a working solution